# get groups of characters n at a time

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to group a string by three (but could be any number) characters at a time. Using this code:

```
"this gets three at a time".scan(/\w\w\w/)
```

I get:

```
["thi","get","thr","tim"]
```

But what I'm trying to get is:

```
["thi","sge","tst","hre","eat","ati","me"]
```

Comment: can you please replace <space> with <empty string> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\w` matches letters digits and underscores (i.e. it's shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`), not spaces. It does not magically skip spaces though, as you seem to expect.

So you'll first have to remove the spaces:

```
"this gets three at a time".gsub(/\s+/, "").scan(/.../)
```

or non-word characters:

```
"this gets three at a time".gsub(/\W+/, "").scan(/.../)
```

before you match the three characters.

Although you should rather use

```
"this gets three at a time".gsub(/\W+/, "").scan(/.{1,3}/)
```

to also obtain the last 1 or 2, if the length is not divisible by 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
 "this gets three at a time".tr(" \t\n\r", "").scan(/.{1,3}/)
```

Comment: yours is a brilliant solution as well and essentially the same as the accepted answer, but I thought I should go with the one which had a complimenting explanation.  I will keep your use of 'tr' in mind for the future, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try these as well:

```
sentence = "this gets three at a time"
sentence[" "] = ""
sentence.scan(/\w\w\w/)  // no change in regex
```

Or:

```
sentence = "this gets three at a time"
sentence[" "] = ""
sentence.scan(/.{1,3}/)
```

Or:

```
sentence = "this gets three at a time"
sentence[" "] = ""
sentence.scan(/[a-zA-Z]{1,3}/)
```

Comment: thanks for the response, it was explained in another post that I would need to remove spaces first.  I guess everyone knows about the {1,3} syntax except me!

Comment: Yeah i told you to do so. Since i found your regex complete but missing the removal of space.